# A String Manipulation Puzzle in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This information I have:

```
Column workflowname has this value ='12STD_Orientations_Workflow'
Column canceldate has a date value
```

I need to assign a value to the column campaignname like this:

let's say the value in canceldate is in November 2012, the value has to be '12STD_Orientations_2012_Nov'. If the value is in January 2013, the value has to be '12STD_Orientations_2013_Jan'. And so on.

I was thinking about doing a function and assign the value of canceldate (in the INSERT clause) by calling `MyFunction(workflowname,canceldate)`. but I don't know how to write the code inside the function!

Comment: What client language are you using, if any? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that will produce the result that you want. This version reverses the current value of the `@str` value and then looks for the first `_` in the string:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '12STD_Orientations_Workflow'
declare @dt datetime = '2012-01-01'


select left(@str, len(@str) - charindex('_', REVERSE(@str))) 
    + '_'
    + cast(YEAR(@dt) as char(4))
    + '_'
    + CONVERT(char(3), @dt, 109)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6692)

Then if you want to place this in a function, you can use:

```
create function dbo.New_Workflow
(
  @origName varchar(200), 
  @dt datetime
)
RETURNS varchar(200) 
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @newvalue varchar(100)
    select @newvalue = left(@origName, len(@origName) - charindex('_', REVERSE(@origName))) 
            + '_'
            + cast(YEAR(@dt) as char(4))
            + '_'
            + CONVERT(char(3), @dt, 109)
    RETURN @newvalue
END;
```

Then to call this you can use:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '12STD_Orientations_Workflow'
declare @dt datetime = '2012-11-01'

select dbo.New_Workflow(@str, @dt)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a00f/2)

The result is:

```
|                    COLUMN_0 |
-------------------------------
| 12STD_Orientations_2012_Nov |
```

Now if you need to pull this from a table, you would use:

```
select dbo.New_Workflow(yourWorkFlowNameCol, yourDateColumn)
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction
(
    @originalString VARCHAR(200), 
    @dateFromField DATETIME
)
RETURNS varchar(200) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @newString VARCHAR(200)
    SELECT @newString = LEFT(@originalString,19) + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@dateFromField,109),3)
    RETURN @newString
END;
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the _Workflow suffix from the WorkflowName value

Comment: Updated to on include the left 19 characters of the original string.  This removes 'Workflow' from the text, but keeps an underscore for use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had to choose one.